# Registrant and Contribution status remains "Partially Paid" even though amount owed was paid off

Tags: civievent, civicontribute, contributions

**STEPS:**
1. User buys tickets for an event (e.g. 2) - this is set up as a Price Set w/ a Text / Numeric Quantity price field
2. Later wants to buy more - CiviCRM admin goes to the contact record, locates the event and using Change Selections adjusts the number of tickets (e.g. 5)
3. This creates a Balance owed on the event registration and the status of the Registration and the Contribution changes to "Partially Paid"
4. The admin then processes an additional payment for the amount equal to the balance owed using the Record Payment link/function

**RESULT:**
Both the Event and the Contribution statuses remain "Partially Paid"

**EXPECTED:**
The Event Registration status should change to "Registered" and Contribution Status to "Completed"

*QUESTION:*
Do I have this right/wrong?

System: Joomla 3.4.8; CiviCRM 4.6.11
Reproduced on the Joomla demo site

Thanks a lot, P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this may be resolved in 4.7 based on what I read in JIRA (there's a variety of tickets on payments topic so it's hard to tell whether one of them will solve this per se but it seems so). I'll test 4.7 and will come back to this topic if it's not solved. For now, I'll mark this as the answer.

Comment: I am having the exact same issue with 4.6.8 on Drupal 7 only it involves changing "Pending Refund" to "Refunded". Were you able to determine if it is resolved in 4.7? Thanks so much!

Comment: Sorry, Nicole, not yet - I'm planning on validating this when the public release is available (slated for end of January).